# Gráfico do Python não mostra todos os valores no eixo X

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, data, pandas, matplotlib

Usei a biblioteca pandas para ler um arquivo csv e criar um gráfico utilizando matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

brazil_dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/states.csv')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
brazil_dataset.plot('UF', 'Population', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, não aparece todos os estados no eixo x do gráfico e os valores de y estão simplificados. Gostaria de saber como gerar o gráfico completo.

Comment: Consegue compartilhar o dataset?

Comment: Já tentou alterar o tamanho da figura, para ver se aparece todos os dados?

Comment: Infelizmente não estou conseguindo enviar o link do dataset. Em relação a mudar o tamanho; eu já tentei e mesma assim não funcionou, ele continua ocultando as informações.

Comment: Editando a pergunta você não consegue colocar o link?

Answer (score 0):

Imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Estados Brasileiros:

```
estados = np.array(['AC','AL','AP','AM','BA','CE',
                    'DF','ES','GO','MA','MT','MS',
                    'MG','PA','PB','PR','PE','PI',
                    'RJ','RN','RS','RO','RR','SC',
                    'SP','SE','TO'])
```

Dados fictícios:

```
populacao = np.random.randint(1000, size = 27)
```

Criando o dataset:

```
brazil_dataset = pd.DataFrame({'UF': estados, 'Population' : populacao})
```

Plotando o gráfico:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
brazil_dataset.plot('UF', 'Population', ax = ax)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(brazil_dataset['UF'])))
ax.set_xticklabels(brazil_dataset['UF'])
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.show()
```

Em `ax.set_xticks` setamos quantos labels(rótulos) irão existir no gráfico.
Em `ax.set_xticklabels` setamos os labels(rótulos), as strings.

Você também pode plotar sem ser diretamente pelo dataframe:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
plt.plot('UF','Population', data = brazil_dataset)
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.show()
```